# Hashset not updating

Tags: elixir

I am trying to write a web crawler and need to keep track of the visited URLs. To do this I've tried using a HashSet, but I havent been able to update it with new URLs

```
defmodule Crawl do

  @depth 2

  @doc """
  Starts crawling process
  """
  def start(url) do
    visit(url, @depth, HashSet.new)
  end

  defp visit(url, 0, cache) do
  end

  defp visit(url, depth, cache) do
    if Set.member? cache, url do
      IO.puts "Cache hit"
    else
      IO.puts "Crawling [#{depth}] #{url}"
      IO.puts "#{Set.size(cache)}"

      new_cache          = Set.put(cache, url)
      {status, response} = HTTPoison.get(url)
      handle(status, response, depth, new_cache)
    end
  end

  defp handle(:ok, response, depth, cache) do
    %{status_code: code, body: body} = response
    handle(code, body, depth, cache)
  end

  defp handle(:error, response, depth, cache) do
    %{id: id, reason: reason} = response
    handle(400, reason, depth, cache)
  end

  defp handle(200, body, depth, cache) do
    IO.puts "Parsing body..."
    parse(body, depth, cache)
  end

  defp handle(301, body, cache), do: IO.puts 301
  defp handle(400, reason, cache), do: IO.puts reason

  # Parses HTML body
  #
  defp parse(body, depth, cache) do
    body
    |> Floki.find(".entry .first a")
    |> Floki.attribute("href")
    |> Enum.map(fn(url) -> visit(url, depth - 1, cache) end)
  end


end
```

Only the initial URL gets inserted, after that, logging the size keeps returning 1

Any suggestionsa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the new copy of cache is available to the functions that need it. You set it in visit and never return it; the newer versions of the cache never get propagated back up the tree.

Elixir is always pass by value, since the data is immutable. You can't change the value of an argument, all you can do is apply a function to it and return a new data item.

The "elixir" way to do what you want would be to create an Agent to manage the persistent state of visited URL's. See

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html

for an example.

If you did not want to use an Agent for some reason, you would need to return the current state out of visit and then use Enum.reduce in your parse function. 
However, this is really the ideal situation for an Agent.

Comment: Im not sure I understand, I pass in the `new_cache` into the handle function, which recursively calls visit. Wouldnt these calls use the updated variables?

Comment: Yes, but only in the handle function. When you call parse  and pass all the found urls into visit again, it uses the value of cache you pass into parse. The changes to cache never get passed back up the recursion.